# Is it possible to build the main Unity C# project from inside Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Using Visual Studio Community 2019 and Unity 2019.3.10f1 it seems I'm unable to build the DLL directly from Visual Studio.

Looking inside the Unity-created csproj I see that it does set an output path in the debug PropertyGroup

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>Temp\bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;UNITY_2019_3_10;UNITY_2019_3;UNITY_2019;UNITY_5_3_OR_NEWER;UNITY_5_4_OR_NEWER;UNITY_5_5_OR_NEWER;UNITY_5_6_OR_NEWER;UNITY_2017_1_OR_NEWER;UNITY_2017_2_OR_NEWER;UNITY_2017_3_OR_NEWER;UNITY_2017_4_OR_NEWER;UNITY_2018_1_OR_NEWER;UNITY_2018_2_OR_NEWER;UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER;UNITY_2018_4_OR_NEWER;UNITY_2019_1_OR_NEWER;UNITY_2019_2_OR_NEWER;UNITY_2019_3_OR_NEWER;PLATFORM_ARCH_64;UNITY_64;UNITY_INCLUDE_TESTS;ENABLE_AR;ENABLE_AUDIO;ENABLE_CACHING;ENABLE_CLOTH;ENABLE_EVENT_QUEUE;ENABLE_MICROPHONE;ENABLE_MULTIPLE_DISPLAYS;ENABLE_PHYSICS;ENABLE_TEXTURE_STREAMING;ENABLE_UNET;ENABLE_LZMA;ENABLE_UNITYEVENTS;ENABLE_VR;ENABLE_WEBCAM;ENABLE_UNITYWEBREQUEST;ENABLE_WWW;ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES;ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_COLLAB;ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_COLLAB_SOFTLOCKS;ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_ADS;ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_USE_WEBREQUEST;ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_CRASH_REPORTING;ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_PURCHASING;ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_ANALYTICS;ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_UNET;ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_BUILD;ENABLE_CLOUD_LICENSE;ENABLE_EDITOR_HUB_LICENSE;ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_CLIENT;ENABLE_DIRECTOR_AUDIO;ENABLE_DIRECTOR_TEXTURE;ENABLE_MANAGED_JOBS;ENABLE_MANAGED_TRANSFORM_JOBS;ENABLE_MANAGED_ANIMATION_JOBS;ENABLE_MANAGED_AUDIO_JOBS;INCLUDE_DYNAMIC_GI;ENABLE_MONO_BDWGC;ENABLE_SCRIPTING_GC_WBARRIERS;PLATFORM_SUPPORTS_MONO;RENDER_SOFTWARE_CURSOR;ENABLE_VIDEO;PLATFORM_STANDALONE;PLATFORM_STANDALONE_WIN;UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN;UNITY_STANDALONE;ENABLE_RUNTIME_GI;ENABLE_MOVIES;ENABLE_NETWORK;ENABLE_CRUNCH_TEXTURE_COMPRESSION;ENABLE_OUT_OF_PROCESS_CRASH_HANDLER;ENABLE_CLUSTER_SYNC;ENABLE_CLUSTERINPUT;ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_HOST;ENABLE_MONO;NET_STANDARD_2_0;ENABLE_PROFILER;UNITY_ASSERTIONS;UNITY_EDITOR;UNITY_EDITOR_64;UNITY_EDITOR_WIN;ENABLE_UNITY_COLLECTIONS_CHECKS;ENABLE_BURST_AOT;UNITY_TEAM_LICENSE;ENABLE_VSTU;ENABLE_CUSTOM_RENDER_TEXTURE;ENABLE_DIRECTOR;ENABLE_LOCALIZATION;ENABLE_SPRITES;ENABLE_TERRAIN;ENABLE_TILEMAP;ENABLE_TIMELINE;ENABLE_LEGACY_INPUT_MANAGER;CSHARP_7_OR_LATER;CSHARP_7_3_OR_NEWER</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <NoWarn>0169</NoWarn>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>False</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However, that folder is not populated with anything when I build from Visual Studio.

Unity does have a built version available in Library\ScriptAssemblies, but this seems to be rebuilt when the UnityEditor determines that a rebuild is in order. I would like to not have to rely on having the Editor open or tabbing into it to have that rebuild occur.

Is there a setting that the Unity project is overriding to disable building outside of the editor? Is there a way to bypass it?

Comment: Did you check out this thread? https://forum.unity.com/threads/compiling-c-scripts-to-dll-files.318803/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change to not build the dlls by default looks to have been made in 4.1.0.0 ([May, 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/change-log-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2019))

You can also disable this optimization in the Tools for Unity Settings.
[image: Where in Visual Studio to find the switch to disable the full build of projects]